# Prove that f is identically 0

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am trying to prove this but it seems to me something went wrong. could you help me to prove it by contradiction?

Let $(x_m)$ be a real sequence. Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x_m)=0$ for any $m\ge 0$. 
Assume that $f$ is

1. piecewise constant
2. right (or left) continuous.

Prove that $f$ is identically $0$. Use contradiction.

I need to show that the assumption is wrong but i could not figure out how. Thank you.

Comment: $(x_m)$ is **any** real sequence?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is correctly stated? Because, as I read it, you could take $x_m = 0$ for all $m$, and then $f$ need not be identically constant. Probably you mean, as hinted by @tetori, *let $f$ be a real function such that for any real sequence one has etc.*

Comment: But $f(x_m)=0$ for *any* real sequence is trivially equivalent to $f(x)=0$ for any $x$.

Comment: Maybe $x_m$ are the only points of discontinuity for $f$?

Comment: You need to prove that the *assumption* is wrong? Such a strange thing...